# API oauth1.0 authentication via https

Tags: python, api, authentication, ssl, oauth

Alert - Amateur Coder here :)

I want to have a read only access for a particular Reporting API.
This particular API documentation mentions that:

1) All API requests must be made over **HTTPS**. Calls over plain HTTP will fail.

2) Authentication is accomplished via **Oauth 1.0a (two-legged)**

I am using Python 3+ to call the API. And for the SSL certificate I am using **certifi**.

Here is the code I am using for the authentication via oauth

```
import oauth2 as oauth
import time,certifi
consumer = oauth.Consumer(key="***KeyHere***", secret="***SecretHere***")
client = oauth.Client(consumer)
client.ca_certs = certifi.where()

request_token_url = "https://reportapi.xxx.xxx.com"
resp, content = client.request(request_token_url, "GET")

token = oauth.Token(request_token['oauth_token'], request_token['oauth_token_secret'])
```

But it gives me the below error all the time:

> ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:646)

Would be great if someone could give me guidance on this.

How can i do an oauth authentication for this API, with https calls.

Warm Regards

Answer (score 0):

The error is an `SSL` verification failure.

`certifi` has removed 1024-bit CA certs. OpenSSL < 1.0.2 sometimes fail to validate certs which have 2048-bit keys.

Try replacing `client.ca_certs = certifi.where()` with `client.ca_certs = certifi.old_where()` to include old 1024-bit key certs.

check https://pypi.python.org/pypi/certifi

In case the problem persists, you have to manually verify server cert using `ssl` module.
This is how I verify `mail.google.com` cert.

```
import ssl
import certifi
ssl.get_server_certificate(('mail.google.com',443),ca_certs=certifi.old_where())
```

`certifi.where()` didn't work here for `mail.google.com` that's why I've used `certifi.old_where()`. Do this with the server you want to verify. There'll be an `SSLError` exception in case of failure.

Comment: Thanks Nizam. I re-tried it with certifi.old_where(). Unfortunately the error persists. Maybe I should follow an alternative to "certifi"? Any other solution that you could suggest would be great